# Web Forms - Entity Framework Context Disposal

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, memory-management

I have a .NET 4 Web Application (Web Forms) that uses Entity Framework to manage data with a MySQL Database. For every Page, I create the context for this Model in the Page_Load.

```
 string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString();
 MyModel = new MyEntities(connString);
```

Now, in subsequent actions on the Page I can use MyModel to retrieve and update data. This is clean and simple to me, but I always assumed .NET discarded the previous Page's MyModel when a new page request was made. I realize this may not be the case? and Memory may be being used inefficiently.

I have seen a good case being made for incorporating the `using (MyEntities MyModel = new MyEntities (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString()))` that handles disposal, but this does not seem clean if I have 6+ actions on a Page each needing to recreate the context when called (Not that my current method does any better).

Is there a clean way to create a context once on initial Page Load and dispose of it when a new page is called, non-postback is called, or the user's session ends?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override virtual `Dispose` method of System.Web.UI.Control and dispose of your context there:

```
public override void Dispose()
{
  if (MyModel != null)
    MyModel.Dispose();
  base.Dispose();
}
```

Further, you can make `MyModel` into a property with the context created on demand:

```
private MyEntities fMyModel = null;

protected MyEntities MyModel
{
  get
  {
    if (fMyModel == null)
    {
      string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString();
      fMyModel = new MyEntities(connString);
    }
    return fMyModel;
  }
}
```

Then, in `Dispose` work with the field:

```
public override void Dispose()
{
  if (fMyModel != null)
    fMyModel.Dispose();
  base.Dispose();
}
```

Furthermore, you can create a base `Page` class with the above property and `Dispose` override and inherit your pages from it - then you do not need to repeat this code in all your pages.

Comment: I like this concept, still clean and reusable. I will need to create some tests to verify the process in my mind. Great response!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to add a call to Dispose() on your data context in the Unload event on the page.

```
protected void Page_Unload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyModel.Dispose();
}
```

A better way that I think should be used as default for web applications (doesn't matter if it is WebForms or MVC is to create one data context per request and dispose it when the request ends. To do that easily you can use an IoC container framework such as Ninject.